# Sass import error in Rails 3 app - "File to import not found or unreadable: compass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, compass-sass, blueprint-css

I have a Rails 3 app on which I successfully ran `compass init rails ./ --using blueprint`.  I can `@import` files from the /stylesheets directory, but I get an error when I try to `@import compass`.

Right now the app has two simple sass files:

**common.scss**

```
$body-background: blue;
```

**main.scss**

```
@import "common";
//@import "compass";

body { 
  background: $body-background; 
}
```

With the `@import "compass"` line commented out, this works -- I get a blue background, so I know Sass is working.

If I uncomment the line, and try to import `compass` or `blueprint` or anything else, I get an error like this.

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
              Load paths:

                /Users/eric/path/to/myrailsapp/app/stylesheets
        on line 2 of /Users/eric/path/to/myrailsapp/app/stylesheets/main.scss

1: @import "common";
2: @import "compass";
3: 
4: body { 
5:  background: $body-background; 
6: }
```

I had through maybe I had to explicitly tell Sass where to find the Compass gem, so I added an `add_import_path` line to config/compass.rb:

```
require 'compass'
require 'html5-boilerplate'

project_type = :rails
project_path = RAILS_ROOT if defined?(RAILS_ROOT)
add_import_path "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/"  # unfortunately this has no effect

http_path = "/"
css_dir = "public/stylesheets"
sass_dir = "app/stylesheets"
images_dir = "public/images"
javascripts_dir = "public/javascripts"
cache_dir = "tmp/sass-cache"

http_images_path = "/images"
http_stylesheets_path = "/stylesheets"
http_javascripts_path = "/javascripts"
```

I have been googling for two days, and can't determine why I'm having this problem with basic `@import` statements.   How do I tell Sass where to find the Compass and Blueprint libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after help from the amazing Chris Eppstein I was able to find the offending line.  In `config/environments.rb` I had this line:

```
Sass::Plugin.options[:template_location] = {
"#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/stylesheets" => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/stylesheets"
}
```

With the currently versions of Rails (I have 3.0.7) and Compass (0.11.1) this line is **not necessary**.  I added it after following a tutorial.  If sass can't find compass, it might be because this line is messing up your `Sass::Plugin.options[:template_location]`.

Answer (score 21):

I was getting this error.

I changed this line in my application.rb from:

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

to:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))) if defined?(Bundler)
```

Also, make sure the files are names **something.css.sass** NOT **something.sass**

And one other thing, I had an old compass.rb file in my config directory which isn't needed in Rails 3.2. Deleting that also solved this problem for me.

Comment: I created a new Rails 3.2.8 project today and `compass.rb` was the problem. I didn't change anything in `application.rb`. So delete `compass.rb` first.

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this problem by switching to the **`compass-rails`** gem instead of the **`compass`** gem in my Gemfile (don't forget to reboot your server). Just in case someone might come across here.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this error after banging my head over it

I commented this line in my application.rb from:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))) if defined?(Bundler)
```

and uncommented:

```
Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

I am using Rails 3.2.11

Comment: If you've added a new environment, adding to the `%w(development test)`, such as `%w(development test new_env_name)` should be sufficient to get assets to load.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem on my Rails 3.2.0 server by moving out `gem 'compass-rails', '~> 1.0.1'` from the `:assets` group in the `Gemfile`, from a tip in https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/issues/19.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Rails 3.2.13 and compass-rails 1.0.3.

Answer (score 2):

The @import command in Sass imports .scss or .sass files, not .css files.

It looks like something was missed in the install. (maybe the line `compass install blueprint`?) I followed the steps here:
http://compass-style.org/reference/blueprint/ and was unable to recreate the issue.

Comment: Right, I'm trying to include the regular compass and blueprint (scss) files.  The "compass init" line above install blueprint.  Just to confirm I ran the command again -- you can see in the output below that compass thinks everything is installed.

Comment: $ compass install blueprint
identical app/stylesheets/screen.scss 
identical app/stylesheets/partials/_base.scss 
identical app/stylesheets/print.scss 
identical app/stylesheets/ie.scss 
identical public/images/grid.png

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error like this:

In application.rb I had

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

and changed to

```
Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

This was after updating a project from 3.0.3 to 3.2.13