# Error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass. in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, saas

I am given a rails project to configure. 
I am using **UBUNTU** 
Rails 3.1
Ruby 1.9.2

I am facing error below:

```
 File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
 Load path: 
 Sass::Rails::Importer(/Project/app/assets/stylesheets/blueprint.sass)
```

(in /Project/app/assets/stylesheets/blueprint.sass)

I found in `blueprint.sass`, below code is written

```
@import 'compass'
@import "compass/reset"
@import "compass/layout/sticky-footer"
@import '_blueprint'
@include blueprint
```

But there is no compass folder exists in the `stylesheet` folder in rails.I installed `gem compass`.

I am trying to solve this problem since moring but could not get success :S ?
 What should I do to make this work.

Comment: Does this address your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005361/sass-import-error-in-rails-3-app-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-comp

Comment: suggestion above didn't fix it for me did you manage to find the error on this issue perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use compass gem instead of compass-rails gem follow the compass update instructions on github to follow the right steps!