# Updating Gemfile.lock, heroku precompile assets breaks based on compass-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline, compass-sass

Update: forgot to post the error itself: https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/issues/19

Asset Precomp fails during heroku deploy (specifically on the css) - and I get a message like this in the logs when viewing the site:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: compass.)
```

So I've reverted to my old gemfile.lock to fix this problem for now, but I wanted to post it here incase anyone had any ideas for what might be causing it.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.1.4'
gem 'thin'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'
gem "devise", '2.1'
gem 'rails_admin', :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'

#For Heroku
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'yui-compressor'
  gem 'compass-rails'
end
gem 'newrelic_rpm'

#Stripe
gem 'stripe'
gem 'sendgrid'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.12'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
gem 'mail'
gem 'fastercsv'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'albino'
gem 'nokogiri'

#Amazon
gem 'aws-sdk'

#Paperclip
gem 'paperclip', '~> 2.5'

#RedCloth Text
gem 'RedCloth'

# In place editing
gem 'best_in_place'

# Use unicorn as the web server
gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'

# Use Pusher
gem "pusher", "~> 0.8.1"

#Memcached
gem 'dalli' 

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  # database_cleaner is not required, but highly recommended
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

Here is my old Gemfile.lock:

```
 GIT
  remote: git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git
  revision: 0ed7ef9ac500e3eff861df4baa0b103fea32cf6e
  specs:
    rails_admin (0.0.1)
      bbenezech-nested_form (~> 0.0)
      bootstrap-sass (~> 1.4, >= 1.4.1)
      builder (~> 3.0)
      coffee-rails (~> 3.1)
      haml (~> 3.1)
      jquery-rails (~> 1.0)
      kaminari (~> 0.12)
      rack-pjax (~> 0.5)
      rails (~> 3.1)
      remotipart (~> 1.0)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    POpen4 (0.1.4)
      Platform (>= 0.4.0)
      open4
    Platform (0.4.0)
    RedCloth (4.2.9)
    actionmailer (3.1.4)
      actionpack (= 3.1.4)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.4)
      activemodel (= 3.1.4)
      activesupport (= 3.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.6)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.3)
    activemodel (3.1.4)
      activesupport (= 3.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.4)
      activemodel (= 3.1.4)
      activesupport (= 3.1.4)
      arel (~> 2.2.3)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.4)
      activemodel (= 3.1.4)
      activesupport (= 3.1.4)
    activesupport (3.1.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.2.7)
    albino (1.3.3)
      posix-spawn (>= 0.3.6)
    arel (2.2.3)
    aws-sdk (1.3.4)
      httparty (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      uuidtools (~> 2.1)
    bbenezech-nested_form (0.0.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
      jquery-rails
      rails (~> 3.1.0)
    best_in_place (1.1.2)
      jquery-rails
      rails (~> 3.1)
    bootstrap-sass (1.4.3)
      sass-rails (~> 3.1)
    builder (3.0.0)
    cancan (1.6.7)
    capybara (1.1.2)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
      xpath (~> 0.1.4)
    childprocess (0.2.3)
      ffi (~> 1.0.6)
    chunky_png (1.2.5)
    cocaine (0.2.1)
    coffee-rails (3.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
    compass (0.12.1)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      fssm (>= 0.2.7)
      sass (~> 3.1)
    compass-rails (1.0.1)
      compass (~> 0.12.0)
    cucumber (1.1.4)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.2)
      gherkin (~> 2.7.1)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
      term-ansicolor (>= 1.0.6)
    cucumber-rails (1.2.1)
      capybara (>= 1.1.2)
      cucumber (>= 1.1.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.0)
    daemons (1.1.8)
    dalli (1.1.4)
    database_cleaner (0.7.0)
    devise (2.1.0)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.7)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.1.1)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.0.beta.4)
    execjs (1.2.13)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    faraday (0.7.6)
      addressable (~> 2.2)
      multipart-post (~> 1.1)
      rack (~> 1.1)
    fastercsv (1.5.4)
    ffi (1.0.11)
    fssm (0.2.9)
    gherkin (2.7.1)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
    haml (3.1.4)
    hashie (1.2.0)
    hike (1.2.1)
    hpricot (0.8.5)
    httparty (0.8.1)
      multi_json
      multi_xml
    i18n (0.6.0)
    jquery-rails (1.0.19)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.7.3)
    kaminari (0.13.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    kgio (2.7.4)
    mail (2.3.3)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.18)
    multi_json (1.0.4)
    multi_xml (0.4.1)
    multipart-post (1.1.5)
    mysql2 (0.3.11)
    newrelic_rpm (3.3.4.1)
    nokogiri (1.5.0)
    oauth (0.4.5)
    oauth2 (0.5.2)
      faraday (~> 0.7)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    omniauth (1.0.3)
      hashie (~> 1.2)
      rack
    omniauth-facebook (1.2.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.0.0)
    omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
      oauth
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.0)
      oauth2 (~> 0.5.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-twitter (0.0.8)
      omniauth-oauth (~> 1.0)
    open4 (1.3.0)
    orm_adapter (0.0.7)
    paperclip (2.6.0)
      activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.2)
      cocaine (>= 0.0.2)
      mime-types
    pg (0.12.0)
      rake-compiler (~> 0.7)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    posix-spawn (0.3.6)
    pusher (0.8.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      ruby-hmac (~> 0.4.0)
      signature (~> 0.1.2)
    rack (1.3.6)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-pjax (0.5.5)
      hpricot (~> 0.8.4)
      rack (~> 1.3)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.4)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.4)
      actionpack (= 3.1.4)
      activerecord (= 3.1.4)
      activeresource (= 3.1.4)
      activesupport (= 3.1.4)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.4)
    rails3-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.5)
      rails (~> 3.0)
    railties (3.1.4)
      actionpack (= 3.1.4)
      activesupport (= 3.1.4)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    raindrops (0.8.0)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rake-compiler (0.7.9)
      rake
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redcarpet (2.0.1)
    remotipart (1.0.1)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rspec (2.7.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.7.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.7.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.7.0)
    rspec-core (2.7.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.7.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
    rspec-mocks (2.7.0)
    rspec-rails (2.7.0)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.7.0)
    ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.5)
    sass (3.1.12)
    sass-rails (3.1.5)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (~> 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    selenium-webdriver (2.15.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0.9)
      multi_json (~> 1.0.4)
      rubyzip
    sendgrid (1.0.1)
      json
      json
    signature (0.1.2)
      ruby-hmac
    sprockets (2.0.4)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    stripe (1.6.0)
      rest-client (~> 1.4)
    term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
    thin (1.3.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.33)
    uglifier (1.2.4)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    unicorn (4.3.1)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    uuidtools (2.1.2)
    warden (1.1.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)
    yui-compressor (0.9.6)
      POpen4 (>= 0.1.4)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  RedCloth
  albino
  aws-sdk
  best_in_place
  cancan
  capybara
  coffee-rails
  compass-rails
  cucumber-rails
  dalli
  database_cleaner
  devise (= 2.1)
  fastercsv
  jquery-rails (>= 1.0.12)
  mail
  mysql2 (= 0.3.11)
  newrelic_rpm
  nokogiri
  omniauth
  omniauth-facebook
  omniauth-twitter
  paperclip (~> 2.5)
  pg
  pusher (~> 0.8.1)
  rails (= 3.1.4)
  rails3-jquery-autocomplete
  rails_admin!
  redcarpet
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails
  sendgrid
  stripe
  thin
  uglifier
  unicorn
  yui-compressor
```

And here is the new (and causing errors in heroku) Gemfile.lock:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git
  revision: 7e607efb2c5f446e36622a8b6553d1df3fb4245f
  specs:
    rails_admin (0.0.4)
      bbenezech-nested_form (~> 0.0.6)
      bootstrap-sass (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.3)
      builder (~> 3.0)
      coffee-rails (~> 3.1)
      haml (~> 3.1)
      jquery-rails (>= 1.0.17)
      jquery-ui-rails (>= 0.5, < 2)
      kaminari (~> 0.12)
      rack-pjax (~> 0.5)
      rails (~> 3.1)
      remotipart (~> 1.0)
      sass-rails (~> 3.1)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    POpen4 (0.1.4)
      Platform (>= 0.4.0)
      open4
    Platform (0.4.0)
    RedCloth (4.2.9)
    actionmailer (3.1.4)
      actionpack (= 3.1.4)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.4)
      activemodel (= 3.1.4)
      activesupport (= 3.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.6)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.3)
    activemodel (3.1.4)
      activesupport (= 3.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.4)
      activemodel (= 3.1.4)
      activesupport (= 3.1.4)
      arel (~> 2.2.3)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.4)
      activemodel (= 3.1.4)
      activesupport (= 3.1.4)
    activesupport (3.1.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.2.8)
    albino (1.3.3)
      posix-spawn (>= 0.3.6)
    arel (2.2.3)
    aws-sdk (1.5.4)
      httparty (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      uuidtools (~> 2.1)
    bbenezech-nested_form (0.0.6)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    best_in_place (1.1.2)
      jquery-rails
      rails (~> 3.1)
    bootstrap-sass (2.0.3.1)
    builder (3.0.0)
    cancan (1.6.7)
    capybara (1.1.2)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
      xpath (~> 0.1.4)
    childprocess (0.3.2)
      ffi (~> 1.0.6)
    chunky_png (1.2.5)
    cocaine (0.2.1)
    coffee-rails (3.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
    compass (0.12.1)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      fssm (>= 0.2.7)
      sass (~> 3.1)
    compass-rails (1.0.2)
      compass (>= 0.12.0, < 0.14)
    cucumber (1.2.1)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
      gherkin (~> 2.11.0)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
    cucumber-rails (1.3.0)
      capybara (>= 1.1.2)
      cucumber (>= 1.1.8)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.0)
    daemons (1.1.8)
    dalli (2.0.5)
    database_cleaner (0.8.0)
    devise (2.1.0)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.7)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.1.1)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (0.12.10)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    faraday (0.8.1)
      multipart-post (~> 1.1)
    fastercsv (1.5.5)
    ffi (1.0.11)
    fssm (0.2.9)
    gherkin (2.11.0)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
    haml (3.1.6)
    hashie (1.2.0)
    hike (1.2.1)
    hpricot (0.8.6)
    httparty (0.8.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      multi_xml
    httpauth (0.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    jquery-rails (1.0.19)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    jquery-ui-rails (1.0.0)
      jquery-rails
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
    json (1.7.3)
    kaminari (0.13.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    kgio (2.7.4)
    libwebsocket (0.1.3)
      addressable
    mail (2.3.3)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.18)
    multi_json (1.3.6)
    multi_xml (0.5.1)
    multipart-post (1.1.5)
    mysql2 (0.3.11)
    newrelic_rpm (3.4.0)
    nokogiri (1.5.4)
    oauth (0.4.6)
    oauth2 (0.6.1)
      faraday (~> 0.7)
      httpauth (~> 0.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
    omniauth (1.1.0)
      hashie (~> 1.2)
      rack
    omniauth-facebook (1.3.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.0.2)
    omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
      oauth
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.2)
      oauth2 (~> 0.6.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-twitter (0.0.11)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      omniauth-oauth (~> 1.0)
    open4 (1.3.0)
    orm_adapter (0.0.7)
    paperclip (2.7.0)
      activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.2)
      cocaine (>= 0.0.2)
      mime-types
    pg (0.13.2)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    posix-spawn (0.3.6)
    pusher (0.8.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      ruby-hmac (~> 0.4.0)
      signature (~> 0.1.2)
    rack (1.3.6)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-pjax (0.5.9)
      hpricot (~> 0.8.6)
      rack (~> 1.3)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.4)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.4)
      actionpack (= 3.1.4)
      activerecord (= 3.1.4)
      activeresource (= 3.1.4)
      activesupport (= 3.1.4)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.4)
    rails3-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.7)
      rails (~> 3.0)
    railties (3.1.4)
      actionpack (= 3.1.4)
      activesupport (= 3.1.4)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    raindrops (0.9.0)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redcarpet (2.1.1)
    remotipart (1.0.2)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rspec (2.10.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.10.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.10.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.10.0)
    rspec-core (2.10.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.10.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.3)
    rspec-mocks (2.10.1)
    rspec-rails (2.10.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.10.0)
    ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.8)
    sass (3.1.19)
    sass-rails (3.1.6)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    selenium-webdriver (2.22.2)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
      libwebsocket (~> 0.1.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip
    sendgrid (1.0.1)
      json
      json
    signature (0.1.3)
    sprockets (2.0.4)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    stripe (1.7.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.1)
      rest-client (~> 1.4)
    thin (1.3.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.33)
    uglifier (1.2.4)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    unicorn (4.3.1)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    uuidtools (2.1.2)
    warden (1.1.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)
    yui-compressor (0.9.6)
      POpen4 (>= 0.1.4)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  RedCloth
  albino
  aws-sdk
  best_in_place
  cancan
  capybara
  coffee-rails
  compass-rails
  cucumber-rails
  dalli
  database_cleaner
  devise (= 2.1)
  fastercsv
  jquery-rails (>= 1.0.12)
  mail
  mysql2 (= 0.3.11)
  newrelic_rpm
  nokogiri
  omniauth
  omniauth-facebook
  omniauth-twitter
  paperclip (~> 2.5)
  pg
  pusher (~> 0.8.1)
  rails (= 3.1.4)
  rails3-jquery-autocomplete
  rails_admin!
  redcarpet
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails
  sendgrid
  stripe
  thin
  uglifier
  unicorn
  yui-compressor
```

Any ideas what could be causing these issues?

Comment: Possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005361/sass-import-error-in-rails-3-app-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-comp or maybe this issue: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/645

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `gem 'compass-rails'` outside of the :assets group.