# Rails 3.2.12 app sass/compass @import failing in production only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, sass, asset-pipeline, compass-sass

Okay, so I have had this issue before where the @import in my css.scss files required the extension:

```
@import 'layout.css.scss'
```

instead of

```
@import 'layout'
```

Not sure why this only happens in production (locally I have no problems). I hate having to add the extension, not sure why, I guess it just annoys me that I have to type it out? :)

My problem I'm having though is that I cannot seem to get compass to work in production. I'm using the compass-rails gem. I have a _config.css.scss file which has the following imports at the top:

```
@import "compass";
@import "compass/css3";
```

I tried adding css.scss to them and then the files are not found (even locally). So my questions are this:

Is there ANY WAY I can use @import without having to include the file extension(s)?

If not, how do I get Compass to work?

Again this is only affecting me in production.

I've tried a few different things I've found on Stackoverflow already but nothing has helped.

[Sass import error in Rails 3 app - "File to import not found or unreadable: compass"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005361/sass-import-error-in-rails-3-app-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-comp)

The exact error I get when I run the app on production:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 920ms
ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
```

**UPDATE**

I did successfully add .scss to my compass import

```
@import 'compass.scss'
```

This no longer threw the 'file not found' error LOCALLY.

But in production I am still getting this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: compass.scss
```

So this tells me that maybe my Compass gem is not working correctly in production?

Comment: Which version of the compass gem? Which version of Rails? Which config options do you have set related to the asset pipeline in `config/environments/production.rb`? If you are set NOT to compile assets in production then have you precompiled them before deploy?

Comment: Are you precompiling your assets?

Comment: @normalocity I'm using version compass 0.12.2 and compass-rails 1.0.3
@fotanus I am also Heroku does this for me. I have `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true` also because RefineryCMS requires this.
@lolmaus I am using RVM, yes.

Answer (score 8):

Delete your `Gemfile.lock` and
just put  `gem 'compass'` and `gem 'compass-rails'` in Gemfile.
After this try `bundle install` for production env.

Comment: Thanks. Removing my Gemfile.lock file and then recreating it with `bundle install` worked for me.