# Gumby Framework in Rails Project - File to import not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, compass-sass, gumby-framework

I have a simple rails project (ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.13), and I am attempting to incorporate the [Gumby CSS Framework](http://gumbyframework.com/). The framework requires [Compass](http://compass-style.org/), with `modular-scale`.

> *For sake of completeness the majority of the post contains information, skip to the end for the actual problem.*

The working directory is being watched with

```
$ compass watch`
```

Compass was incorporated into the project with:

```
compass create --app rails \
    -l ./app/assets/stylesheets/gumby/ \
    --using modular-scale
```

The contents of `config/compass.rb` is:

```
require 'modular-scale'
project_type = :rails
```

And the location of Gumby source (SCSS) is `app/assets/stylesheets/gumby`.

The resulting compiled css appears in `public/assets/gumby/gumby.css`.

The following is within my Gemfile

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'modular-scale'
  gem 'gumby-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

And `bundle install` completes without errors.

**However...**

The following error message appears on all served pages:

### Sass::SyntaxError in Users#index

Showing PROJECT_ROOT/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: compass/typography/vertical_rhythm.
Load path: Sass::Rails::Importer(PROJECT_ROOT/app/assets/stylesheets/gumby/_base.scss)
  (in PROJECT_ROOTr/app/assets/stylesheets/gumby/_base.scss)
```

After hours of tinkering, I am at a loss as to the reason why Sass cannot read the Compass library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after much digging, I've found a way to incorporate Gumby into Rails, however I've lost the ability to edit the scss in the process. I did this using the [`gumby-framework`](https://github.com/jorgecoca/gumby-framework) gem. Setup was simple, following the README.

Comment: Yea. i am at the same point. I'd really like to be able to put an override file in with the gumby sass source files and have rails do the compilation for easy changeability

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9021785/1280997.

Removing `config/compass.rb` and rebooting the server fixes the immediate problem, however I am now faced with:

```
Undefined mixin 'box-sizing'.
  (in PROJECT_ROOT/app/assets/stylesheets/gumby/_base.scss)
```